# Does cloudformation create new resources before deleting old ones?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

From anecdotal evidence, I've noticed that CloudFormation updates seem to create new resources and update existing ones before deleting removed resources.  However, I haven't been able to find any documented evidence that this is an explicit behavior rather than just a general rule.

I'm adding an SQS queue between an SNS topic and a lambda, and I cannot afford to miss a single message in the process - is CloudFormation actually guaranteed to create the new resources and subscriptions before it deletes the old SNS-> lambda subscription?  My lambda is set up to accept both message formats, to be cleaned up afterward.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour depends on the resource and property that are changed. Some changes can be done on the existing resource itself without interruption; others require a replacement. This is [documented on the AWS website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-update-behaviors.html). Of course, the new resource is created first and only after successful provisioning, the old resource will be replaced.

The Cloudformation docs for each property of each resource type indicates what happens on an update. See for example the [docs for the `AWS::EC2::Instance` resource type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html) (Note the *Update requires* entries).

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, this question was about multiple resources in a single stack deployment rather than updating a single resource.  If resource A (SQS queue) is created, resource B (lambda) is updated, and resource C (SNS subscription) is removed - is it actually guaranteed that resources A and B will be acted on before resource C is?

Comment: I can’t say if it’s guaranteed (can’t find docs right away), but I can say that I have always experienced it this way in a variety of scenarios: First create new resources, then update existing ones and finally remove obsolete ones.